# Is callus totipotent or pluripotent?

Tags: cell-biology, botany

Is callus (in the context of plant tissue culture) totipotent or pluripotent? As I understand, the difference between totipotency and pluripotency is an ability to differentiate into extraembryonic cells. So, I stuck on the question: what is extraembryonic plant cells and could callus cells differentiate into it?